# Space inserted after link

Tags: html, css, fonts, hyperlink, html-email

Working in Eloqua.

Does anyone know what could cause a space to be added to a link? It does not show the space in a test proof, only in the live version.

Code:

```
<p style="line-height:18px;">
  <font face="calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"
        color="#333333"
        style="font-size:16px;">
    xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx <strong>xxxxx</strong> xxxxxx&nbsp;
    <a href="http://www.xxxx.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#ed1c24">xxxx.com</a>.
    <font size="2" color="#666666">(xxxxxx,&nbsp;xxxx)</font>
  </font>
</p>
```

Comment: Indent each line of your HTML by four spaces (or more), and post actual HTML.

Comment: <p style="line-height:18px;"> <font face="calibri, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" color="#333333" style="font-size:16px;">xxxxxx <strong>xxxxx (xxx&nbsp;xxx)</strong> xxx xxx xxx xxx xxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxx. xxxx&rsquo;x xxxxx&nbsp;<a href="http://www.xxxxx.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#ed1c24">xxxxx.com</a>. <font size="2" color="#666666">(xxxxxx)</font></font></p>

Answer (score 0):

Since the code here appears to be working, I'd recommend viewing the source code in rendered email - perhaps via the 'view as a web page' link. I've seen this before, it was always due to a copy+paste character from Photoshop.